# Changing variables to solve a related ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> By first finding the general real solution to $\frac{d^4u}{dt^4}+2\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=4t^4$, and then considering the change of variables $u(t) = y(t^2)$, find the general real solution to
>
> $$4x^2\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}+12x\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+(3+2x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=x$$

Solving the first DE is bookwork: $u(t) = A\sin(\sqrt{2}t)+B\cos(\sqrt{2}t)+\frac{t^4}{6}-t^2+Ct+D$.

Using the hint (and a lot of chain rule), I get that the first DE can be recast as
$$4t^4\frac{d^4y}{dt^4}+12t^2\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}+(3+2t^2)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}=t^2$$

This is very similar to the second DE above, but with $x=t^2$ in the coefficients. Of course, I can't just substitute since then I would need to compute each derivative, and defeats the point of the question.

Wolfram Alpha spat out $y(x) = Ae^{i\sqrt{2x}}+iBe^{-i\sqrt{2x}}+\frac{x^2}{6}-x+C\sqrt{x}+D$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2y%27%27%27%27(x)%2B12xy%27%27%27(x)%2B(3%2B2x)y%27%27(x)%2By%27(x)%3Dx). Again, similar but not quite. I am also only asked for the most general *real* solution.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your work so I can't tell where you did wrong, but the correct result should be

$$4t^4\frac{d^4y}{d\color{red}{x}^4}+12t^2\frac{d^3y}{d\color{red}{x}^3}+(3+2t^2)\frac{d^2y}{d\color{red}{x}^2}+\frac{dy}{d\color{red}{x}}=t^2$$

i.e. all the derivatives are w.r.t $x$, not $t$. Now you can swap out $t^2$ for $x$ to get the final answer.